# AWS SNS Applications - Get Name of the Platform Applications via API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am using the `listPlatformApplications()` method of `AmazonSNSClient` which returns the list of `PlatformApplication` objects. But `PlatformApplication` object only has ARN and one attribute names "Enabled" . I want to get the Name of the PlatformApplication. How can I do that?

Comment: Hi @g.revolution Did you get answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`AmazonSNSClient.getPlatformApplicationAttributes(GetPlatformApplicationAttributesRequest`)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/AmazonSNSClient.html#getPlatformApplicationAttributes-com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.GetPlatformApplicationAttributesRequest-)

You can pass the ARN from `PlatformApplication` to [`GetPlatformApplicationAttributesRequest`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sns/model/GetPlatformApplicationAttributesRequest.html) to retrieve the attributes with this method.